# Running andengine GLES2 using emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, opengl-es-2.0, andengine

This is my first game and i choosed AndEngine library. My avd configuration have its target as Android 4.2.2 API Level 17 and GPU emulation enabled. Yet I am getting the following error in my console

> [2013-08-29 22:05:13 - AndEngine1] Android Launch!
>   [2013-08-29 22:05:13 - AndEngine1] adb is running normally.
>   [2013-08-29 22:05:14 - AndEngine1] Performing com.example.andengine1.MainActivity activity launch
>   [2013-08-29 22:05:25 - AndEngine1] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'small2'
>   [2013-08-29 22:06:52 - Emulator] creating window 0 0 240 432
>   [2013-08-29 22:06:53 - AndEngine1] New emulator found: emulator-5554
>   [2013-08-29 22:06:53 - AndEngine1] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
>   [2013-08-29 22:08:11 - AndEngine1] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.example.andengine1.MainActivity activity launch'!
>   [2013-08-29 22:09:02 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetUniformLocation:1380 error 0x501
>   [2013-08-29 22:09:04 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetUniformLocation:1380 error 0x501
>   [2013-08-29 22:09:04 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:1911 error 0x501
>   [2013-08-29 22:09:04 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetUniformLocation:1380 error 0x501
>   [2013-08-29 22:09:12 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:1911 error 0x501
>   [2013-08-29 22:09:15 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:1911 error 0x501

and so on
Pls help me regarding this to fix the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please provide relevant code, not only logcat trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to install 'intel X86' in the extras section in the SDK Manager .
   After installing 'intel X86' also if your system is showing problem such as "HXA not installed " , that means you have to check whether your system supports virtualization .
   Suppose your system doesnt support virtualization , then you can't run your game on emulator . 
   Emulator requires virtualization enabled in the system .

If your system doesn't support virtualization , then
You should run using real smart phone which has android OS in it to test your game.

stems 
If your system supports virtualization , then you have to enable virtualization to run your game on emulator .
Virtualization(VT) is a hardware related thing.  Some sy